# How do I create a unique index for exactly one field in Mongo shell, while inserting multiple fields for each of my objects at once?

Tags: mongodb, key, unique-index

I'm currently using the MongoDB shell v5.0.10 to set up a database for further use and was wondering if it is possible to combine the following commands into one command (and how):

```
 db.customers.insertMany([
     {"customer": "Bosch", "city": "Stuttgart",  "AccNo": 70174, "orders": 1088},
     {"customer": "ZDF",   "city": "Mainz",      "AccNo": 55116, "orders": 40530},
     {"customer": "EF",    "city": "Düsseldorf", "AccNo": 40479, "orders": 178650}
 ])
```

including:

```
db.customers.createIndex({"AccNo": 40479}, {unique: true})
```

Ideally, I'd have a one line command like:

```
db.customers.insertMany([
    {"customer": "Bosch", "city": "Stuttgart",  "AccNo": 70174 {unique: true}, "orders": 1088},
    {"customer": "ZDF",   "city": "Mainz",      "AccNo": 55116 {unique: true}, "orders": 40530},
    {"customer": "EF",    "city": "Düsseldorf", "AccNo": 40479 {unique: true}, "orders": 178650}
])
```

.. doing all that at once.

If not obvious:

I'm trying to have the "AccNo" as a unique index, while also assigning & creating all the other stated fields & values above - so I don't have to create an _id, neither using the automatically created cryptic ObjectId for calling Objects later on.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't combined the two, but once the index is created the constraint will be kept through all the inserts

Comment: `db.customers.createIndex({"AccNo": 40479}, {unique: true})`  Does that work?  I thought for a single field numeric index the value should be `1` or `-1`.